# No access to wordpress functions from plugin files

Tags: wordpress

I came across this problem when I was creating a plugin. I cannot call(access ) wordpress default functions like **`wp_get_current_user()`, `$wpdb->get_results()`, `admin_url()`** etc. from my plugin files. I can access them from my main file of that plugin in which plugin description is given. But I cannot access them from other plugin files. At that time I heard that if we create a new file functions.php and put these code in that file inside a function I can access all wordpress functions. I did so. But now I cannot access that new function. How can I solve this problem? I think you guys understood what I said. Please help me.

Comment: I guess you are calling your plugin file like this: `example.com/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/plugin-file.php`? In that case, indeed, you won't be able to access WordPress functionality because that file does not load the WordPress code. There are different ways to do this, but you should specify what you are trying to do with this file: load it in the admin side or in the front site? Use it to handle form submissions? Display style information? Edit your question to give more information, and leave a comment (If you use `@Jan` in your comment I get a notification)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@Jan : I got the required thing. I just put `require_once('../../../wp-load.php');` in my plugin files and now can access all wp functions from there. Any ways thanks for your reply.

Comment: Actually I was using it to handle ajax request.